# Detecting the avatar's position in relation to the camera's angle

Tags: unity, camera, angles, avatar

How to detect the avatar's position in relation to the camera's angle.

I want to detect whether the camera is facing the avatar's lef, right or back side.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Is it a 3rd-person camera or a free-movement camera? Do you mean the Y-axis camera angle, or a more flexible `lookAt` direction vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [InverseTransformPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformPoint.html) to get the camera's position expressed in the local coordinate space of the avatar. Then you just need to check which component of that vector is farthest from zero, and in what direction.

I've shown a version that categorizes all 6 pyramids around the avatar (including "top" and "bottom"), but you can delete the `y` sections if you just want to categorize positions in 4 wedges — left/right/front/back.

```
public enum Side {
    Left,
    Right,
    Top,
    Bottom,
    Front,
    Back
}

public Side WhichSideOf(Vector3 position, Transform relativeTo) {
    var local = relativeTo.InverseTransformPoint(position);

    var squared = Vector3.Scale(local, local);

    if (squared.x > squared.y) {
        if (squared.x > squared.z) {
            return local.x > 0 ? Side.Right : Side.Left;
        } else {
            return local.z > 0 ? Side.Front : Side.Back;
        }
    } else if (squared.y > squared.z) {
        return local.y > 0 ? Side.Top : Side.Bottom;
    } else {
        return local.z > 0 ? Side.Front : Side.Back;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

On top of my head, I would create a forward, left, right, and back vector on the "Avatar". You can then calculate the vector between the camera and avatar and use that as a dot product. From there, I *THINK* that the highest dot value is the one facing the camera most.

Comment: A good answer will go into more detail than this, often with specific code examples. Short answers that give a general direction, rather than specific steps, are generally better left as comments.